# Multiple Tables Into One Object?

Tags: database, oop

If I have two tables, one a "user" table which holds login info and another table, "profile" which stores info like names.  Would it be more practical to map those two tables into one object in code or would keeping those two tables as separate objects in code be more efficient?

Comment: This question is quite broad and may be objected to by some. But both approaches can be used. use the approach which makes your code the cleanest.

Comment: Adding to the comment above by @johnelemans it depends on your end-use case as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display/use the "user" and the "profile" information at the same time then keep them together and load via join. If login is purely login info and you don't need to use the info for any other purpose except logging in then keep them separate as you can get to the profile from login table. As said in the comments it depends upon how you intend to use the data in these 2 tables.